# Why is the first layer of my Linkedlist not printing?

Tags: java

I am trying to show adjacency between two objects through a linked list. When I tried to print out the adjacencies it skips the first row. This is what prints out:

```
X



X

R   >>>   W

S   >>>   Y

T

W

R   >>>   Z
```

And it's supposed to be:

```
Q   >>>   X
R   >>>   x
P   >>>   R   >>>   W
W   >>>   S   >>>   Y
S   >>>   T
T   >>>   W
Y   >>>   R   >>>   Z
```

As you can see, only the second and third levels are printed out, and not all of them.

Relevant code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    FlightMap flights = new FlightMap();
    flights.loadFlightMap("cityFile.txt", "flightFile.txt");
    Scanner requestInStream = null;

    requestInStream = new Scanner(new File("requestFile.txt"));

    //DEBUGGING
    String[] str = new String[] {"Q", "X", "R", "P", "W", "S", "T", "Y", "Z"};
    String temp = null;
    for ( int x = 0; x < str.length; x++) {
        temp = str[x];
        City city = new City(temp);
        flights.displayAdjacentCities(city);
    }
```

FlightMap class

```
//Read in the files from the main...
private int size = 0;
private City[] allCities;
private LinkedList<City>[] adjacents;

public FlightMap() {
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void loadFlightMap(String cityFileName, String flightFileName)
        throws FileNotFoundException {


    Scanner inStream = null;
    inStream = new Scanner(new File(cityFileName));
    while(inStream.hasNextLine()) {
        size++;
        inStream.nextLine();
    }
    inStream.close();
    allCities = new City[size];
    adjacents = (LinkedList<City>[]) new LinkedList[size];

    for(int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
        adjacents[x] = new LinkedList<City>();
    }

    Scanner inStream1 = null;
    inStream1 = new Scanner (new File(cityFileName));
    for(int x = 0; x <size; x++) {
        String input = inStream1.nextLine();
        allCities[x] = new City (input);
    }

    inStream1 = new Scanner (new File(flightFileName));
    String data;
    while (inStream1.hasNext()) {
        int flag = 0;
        data = inStream1.next();
        for (int i = 0; i < size && flag !=1; i++) {
            if(allCities[i].getName().equalsIgnoreCase(data)) {
                data = inStream1.next();
                for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                    if (allCities[j].getName().equalsIgnoreCase(data)) {
                        adjacents[i].add(allCities[j]);
                        flag = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    inStream1.close();
}
```

Display adjacency method:

```
public void displayAdjacentCities(City aCity) { 
    for(int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
        if (aCity.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(allCities[x].getName())) {
            Iterator<City> iter = adjacents[x].iterator();
            while(iter.hasNext()) {
                System.out.print(iter.next().getName());
                if(iter.hasNext()) {
                    System.out.print("   >>>   ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
    }
```

All the objects are in the cityFile:
(Each on a separate line)

```
Q
X
R
P
W
S
T
Y
Z
```

Adjacencies are in the flightFile (separated by a tab between two letters and a each pair on a separate line:

```
Q   X
R   X
P   R
P   W
W   S
S   T
T   W
W   Y
Y   R
Y   Z
```

And desired paths are in the requestFile:

```
Q   X
P   X
P   T
P   Z
P   X
P   Q
T   P
A   S
R   X
T   X
Q   X
```

I am not sure if I am asking the right question(s).

Comment: Please highlight the area where are you getting some problem.

Comment: @Nikhil I think I am reading the file wrong... Or the my adjacency method isn't right. I don't know how to actually test either one of those. The City array, reads in fine, but I am not sure about the flightFile.

Comment: Did you try debugging it? It is a very useful and must learnt tool.

Comment: @baraky I tried, but I not sure how to do that either...

Comment: @user1864651 what IDE do you use?

Comment: @baraky Eclipse. My efforts in trying to debug is putting link breakpoints everywhere and trying to follow along. Then I get confused at what I am trying to look for.

Comment: @user1864651 I think you should try and debug it yourself. If you get to something you don't know, you can ask. But debugging is a skill you **must** learn.

Comment: Just one question: When you are trying to find adjacent cities, do you want all reachable cities possible or do you just want the city reachable directly. Your code currently does the latter, but have a hunch that you want all possible reachable cities from any given city.

Comment: @prashant I want all the reachable cities.

Comment: Well in that case your approach won't work. Hint: You should think about using recursion. Try to recursively find the next reachable city. This is similar to the TSP problem except that you want all paths instead of the best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample answer looks as though a city should be considered adjacent to itself?
Try this:

```
public void displayAdjacentCities(City aCity) { 
  for(int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
    if (aCity.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(allCities[x].getName())) {
       if (adjacents[x].size() == 0) continue;
       System.out.print(aCity.getName());
       for (City other : adjacents[x]) {
                System.out.print("   >>>   " + other.getName()); 
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```